# SQL Inner join Script issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL and am having a issue with inner joins. I have `Trader` Table with `trader_id`,`contact_id` and `last ordered` and `Contact` table with `trader_id` and `contact_id`.

When I run below script the `trader_id` and `contact_id` are exactly the same where I would have expected `trader_id`,`contact_id` (different value to `trader_id`) and `last ordered date`.
Script:

```
select  trader.trader_id
       ,contact.contact_id
       ,last_ordered 
from trader trader  
join contact contact on trader.trader_id=contact.contact_id
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should be joining on same columns names..

Comment: You have said "When I run below script the trader_id and contact_id are exactly the same where I would have expected trader_id,contact_id( different value to trader_id) and last ordered date."

Now check the filter - trader.trader_id = contact.contact_id. This makes sure that it brings back results which has contact id equal to trader id.

Comment: Slight detour....if you are going to use aliases you really should use a different name than the name of the table or the point of the alias is lost.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select  trader.trader_id
       ,contact.contact_id
       ,last_ordered 
from trader trader  
join contact contact on trader.trader_id=contact.trader_id -- (trader_id not contact_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  trader.trader_id
   ,contact.contact_id
   ,last_ordered 
from trader  
inner join contact on trader.trader_id=contact.trader_id
```

Comment: What is different than the original question? And you didn't say what is wrong.

Comment: you just had a join. I changed it to inner join

Comment: join is shortcut/alias for inner join

Comment: Hmm. Join and Inner Join have the same affect. But you should change to trader_id for the join on both tables.